# C++ json insert into array

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am using nlohmann json. I want to insert into an array. I know in javascript there is a `Array.prototype.splice` that allows you to insert into an array. Is there a similar way in nlohmann's json.

I want this to happen:

```
//from this:
[1, 2, 3, 5]

//insert at position 3 the value 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Basically I want something similar to the `std::vector` insert method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show in the question a [mre] which includes what you have already tried (as code), the error, the input, and the expected output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example should work, assuming you're using the single-include `json.hpp` and it's in the set of include directories used by your compiler. Otherwise, modify the `#include` as needed.:

```
#include "json.hpp"                                      
#include <iostream>                                      

int main() {                                             
  nlohmann::json json = nlohmann::json::array({0, 1, 2});
  std::cout << json.dump(2) << "\n\n";                     
  json.insert(json.begin() + 1, "foo");                  
  std::cout << json.dump(2) << '\n';                     
}
```

This should print:

```
[
  0,
  1,
  2
]

[
  0,
  "foo",
  1,
  2
]
```