# nlohmann json insert an array into another array

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I want to take these two arrays:

```
[1, 2, 5]

[3, 4]
```

and insert the `[3, 4]` into position 2 of `[1, 2, 5]`. 
The result would look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You just asked (and got an answer, from me!) this question yesterday... [C++ json insert into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358607/c-json-insert-into-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v1 ={1, 2, 5};
    std::vector<int> v2 ={3,4};

    std::vector<int> v3=v1;//will hold the new one
    v3.insert(v3.begin()+2,v2.begin(),v2.end());
    //To see the result
    std::ostream_iterator<int> printer{std::cout, " "};
    std::copy(v3.begin(),v3.end(), printer);
}
```